# How to share wineprefix?

Tags: permissions, wine

I want to share a wineprefix between two users on my computer, so that both of them could run Windows programs installed in there. To do so, i moved wineprefix in /usr/share, created a common group for both of those users, and set group of wineprefix and all its files to that group.

However, when i tried to run program from that wineprefix as other user, all i got was "you are not owner" error message from wine.

As far as i can tell, this is 'by design' to prevent running wine programs as root.

Is there a way to achieve my goal? Note, that i want to share wineprefix, not make several copies of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This topic has already discussed in the below forum topic,

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=917422

Probably this could help you in setting up your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is an ancient question, but I have a solution that I think is much simpler and better.

Wine only checks whether you own the top-level directory of the wine prefix. Therefore, you can simply make a new directory and put symbolic links to all the contents of the wineprefix you want to share in that directory.

This is what I would recommend:

1. Create a user, we'll call it wineuser

   `sudo adduser wineuser`
2. Log in as wineuser
3. Create a wine prefix
   Simply run

`winecfg`

for a 64-bit prefix or

`WINEARCH=win32 winecfg`

for a 32-bit prefix.

4. Modify the permissions of the wine prefix to be readable and writable by everyone in the group wineuser

   `chmod -R 770 /home/wineuser/.wine`
5. For each user you will need to add them to the group wineuser and make a directory of links to serve as their access point to the wine prefix. For user emily, we would run:

   `` mkdir /home/emily/.wineshared
   sudo adduser emily wineuser
   cd /home/wineuser/.wine
   for object in `ls /home/wineuser/.wine`;
   do ln -s -T /home/wineuser/.wine/$object /home/emily/.wineshared/$object;
   done ``

That's it! emily now can run programs in the shared wineprefix by using WINEPREFIX=~/.wineshared